# Warning keep popping when running conque in VIM

Tags: vim, plugins

When running `conque` in `VIM`, the warning message prompts out every time:

```
Warning: 
Global CursorHoldI and CursorMovedI autocommands may cause ConqueTerm to run slowly
```

I found a method to remove the warning is to comment out the warning-function in the `conque_term.vim`, but I don't think it's a decent and safe way to solve the problem.

I'm new with VIM, so I found no way to identify the source of problem by myself. Could anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some of your plugins are probably defining `autocmd`s on these events. An autocompletion plugin, maybe, or a tag-generation plugin… Grep your `~/.vim/` directory for `CursorHoldI` and/or `CursorMovedI` or do `:verbose autocmd` to see where these are defined.

Comment: BE CAREFUL... autocommands can cause major problems with ConqueTerm, it can cause open buffers to be overwritten with it's output and all sorts of other nasty things. It can be down-right dangerous. I cannot recommend it for anyone who uses lots of plugins that intercept the Cursor auto commands, as it seems that even when mixed with a small amount of these, bad things happen. Just remember not to accidentally save any of those bad changes, should they happen. Try disabling plugins & re-enable them one by one to find the culprit. Hopefully using pm like vundle which makes it easy to do this!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One integration point into Vim is through events, which can trigger automatic commands; the *Conque* plugin itself uses these to implement its functionality. Events like `CursorMovedI` are fired whenever you type something or move the cursor in insert mode; this can have an impact on performance, and that's what the warning is about.

You can list all such automatic commands via:

```
:verbose autocmd CursorHoldI,CursorMovedI
```

As long as *Conque* works well for you, it's fine to ignore (and suppress) the warning. But if you indeed run into problems, you'd need to check the other autocmd sources and maybe disable one or the other plugin (at least for the *Conque* buffer). (See `:help autocmd-remove` for how to do this.)

Comment: You can also suppress this warning with `let g:ConqueTerm_StartMessages = 0` (see https://code.google.com/p/conque/wiki/Usage#3.1.8_Hide_start_messages)

Answer (score 2):

Off topic, but using Ctrl+Z to drop back to shell and fg to return to vim seems to work way better than Conque. That is if you're using vim from the terminal, which you should.

Some inspiration: http://statico.github.com/vim.html

Comment: It does not "work way better", it is a different tool for a different scenario. I like to start up vim as soon as I open a terminal, so that I can run my terminal commands from inside conque so they will be inside a vim buffer. This allows me to use normal vim commands to search through, copy from, and jump around in terminal output. Once you like the ability to do these things in vim, you want to do them everywhere, especially the terminal. Typically, I only go back to the normal terminal if I need to run a separate instance of vim since running vim inside vim via conque does not work well.