# NeoVim terminal plugins don't work after arch/manjaro update

Tags: linux, vim-plugin, neovim, arch, conque

recently I had a system update on my manjaro system.

Generally I don't do system updates (not just because in linux they are generally unecessary but also because of things like these), and my plugin to emulate the bash terminal in vim just stopped working.

By this I mean, you could write whatever you want it would never output.

All it printed was this:

```
Python 2 interface is not installed, using Python 3 instead
Warning: Global CursorHoldI and CursorMovedI autocommands may cause Terminal to run slowly.
Warning: Global CursorHoldI and CursorMovedI autocommands may cause Terminal to run slowly.
```

And after that, you can press enter but it wouldn't work.

Now I have already tried 3 things, all of them not working.

1. I followed up [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996462/warning-keep-popping-when-running-conque-in-vim#14997179), which, didn't help me that much
2. Instead of vim-terminal (the emulator I was using for neovim), I installed Conque. (Thinking this was a config problem that I could have worked it out by simply trying another alternative)
3. Downgrading bash and/or python

None of those gave me the right outcomes.

If anybody could help me fix this I would be thankfull.

Thanks.

**Update**: vim-terminal and conque are deprecated. Use neovim native terminal instead.

Comment: FWIW, Neovim (and Vim since two versions) has its own built-in terminal emulator that works a hell of a lot better than conque.

Comment: I am testing it. Don't know why the tutorial that I saw didn't suggested it.

Comment: It was probably way too old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution added to the question in the **Update**.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).